# My custom Outlook Add-in is causing Excel Save dialog box to hide itself

Tags: c#, excel, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have created an Outlook Add-In that adds a button to the ribbon of a new email window, but it's causing a problem.

Here is what happens:

1. User has Outlook Open.
2. User opens Excel.
3. User sends excel document to someone via File->Save and Send->Send as Attachment
4. User makes a change to the document
5. User attempts to close the document
6. This is when Outlook prompts the user to save the file, but the dialog box is hidden behind the Excel window and the user can't get to it without doing some shenanigans.

My Outlook Add-in does many other things, but I've pinned it down to the Ribbon.cs file I created to add a button to the new email window.  When I change the RibbonType property of the OfficeRibbon object from Micorosft.Outlook.Mail.Compose to nothing, the Save Dialog shows as it should.  When I change it back to "Compose", it hides the dialog box again.

Does anyone know of any way around this?  I have confirmed this happens when the project is either an Outlook 2007 Add-In or an Outlook 2010 Add-In.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/outlookdev/thread/688ed11a-59e4-4778-b956-fc8a7cbaec14?prof=required

Answer (score 1):

So in reference to the link sent by user1217053 the answer would probably be along the lines of...

create a class scope field for the Outlook.Mailitem
have it bind to the BeforeClose event.

Inside the BeforeClose event handler for this field, add code such as ...

```
cMailItem_BeforeClose(bool Cancel)
{
  var Insp = cMailItem.GetInspector();
  Insp.Close();
  Marshal.FinalReleaseCOMObject(Insp);
  Insp = null;
}
```

Then hopefully this will get rid of the shadow inspector.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you are still working on with this problem or not, but I faced the exact same problem and then found the solution. You must be using the Ribbon designer just like I was. The ribbon designer cause this problem. I had to change from Ribbon designer to Ribbon XML. It was a little bit of work to remove code and change some logic, but that fixed the problem. I heard the other altenative is to use a wrapper class.

Hope this helps.